# Data is not getting fetched before rendering component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am able to build login functionality with react + springboot + postgres. After login, when JWT is stored in localstore, my app redirects to `/profile` page for which I am rendering `<Profile />` component, which looks like this:

**Profile.js**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import UserDataService from '../services/user.services'

export default function ProfileModule(props) {

    const [userDetails, setUserDetails] = useState(undefined);

    const retrieveUserDetails = () => {
        console.log('Retrieving data')
        UserDataService.getUserDetails()
          .then(response => {
            setUserDetails(response.data);
            console.log(response.data);
          })
          .catch(e => {
            console.log(e);
          });
      };

    useEffect(() => {
        retrieveUserDetails();
    }, []);
      
    return (
        <div style={{paddingLeft:50, marginTop: -20}}>
            <h1> Welcome {userDetails.firstName + " " + userDetails.lastName} + "," </h1>
            <br />
            User Name: {userDetails.userName}
            <br />
            Phone Number: {userDetails.phone}
            <br />
            Email: {userDetails.email}
        </div> 
    )
}
```

But while rendering above component, I am getting

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstName' of undefined
ProfileModule
../client/src/components/Profile.js:26
  23 |   
  24 | return (
  25 |     <div style={{paddingLeft:50, marginTop: -20}}>
> 26 |         <h1> Welcome {userDetails.firstName + " " + userDetails.lastName} + "," </h1>
     | ^  27 |         <br />
  28 |         User Name: {userDetails.userName}
  29 |         <br />
```

Somehow `userDetails` is not getting populated. I debugged in chrome with breakpoints on `retrieveUserDetails` and `useEffect` and also on `user.services.getUserDetails()`. But no breakpoint is getting hit. Also none of those `console.log()`s are visible. What I am missing?

**user.services.js**

```
import axios from "axios";
import authHeader from "./auth-header";

const API_URL = "http://localhost:8080/api/test/";

const getUserDetails = () => {
    const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
    return axios.get(API_URL + "userdetails/" + user.username, { headers: authHeader() } );
}

export default {
  getUserDetails,
};
```

(I tested the end point `http://localhost:8080/api/test/userdetails/username` in Postman and it is retrieving the details.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `ProfileModule` renders *immediately* when called - it doesn't wait for the effect callback to complete before rendering.

Change your rendered JSX to only render after the data has been received.

```
return !userDetails ? null : (
    <div style={{paddingLeft:50, marginTop: -20}}>
        <h1> Welcome {userDetails.firstName + " " + userDetails.lastName} + "," </h1>
        <br />
        User Name: {userDetails.userName}
        <br />
        Phone Number: {userDetails.phone}
        <br />
        Email: {userDetails.email}
    </div> 
)
```

You can also simplify

```
useEffect(() => {
    retrieveUserDetails();
}, []);
```

to

```
useEffect(retrieveUserDetails)
```

Comment: I get the null check, but wouldn't the component just re-render when the state changes that being when the getUserDetails request is completed. If I'm not missing anything, the problem should lie somewhere else.

Comment: Once the component re-renders after the request completes, `userDetails` will be populated, so the `:` branch of the conditional will be entered into and `userDetails.firstName` won't throw.

Comment: If I manually hit the link `/profile` or by clicking another button which takes me to `/profile` sometime after initial failure (so that the data is received properly), should my code (not with your change) work correctly? If no, why?

Comment: @Rnj No - the initial state is always `undefined`, you're not taking the initial state from somewhere else like props or context. If you unmount the component by going to some other component and then coming back, the component will run its initial code again and assign `undefined` to the initial state. If this component here isn't always mounted, a better approach would be to put the state in a parent component, and then pass it down.

Comment: Surprisingly how quickly and precisely you answer! Experience!!!